# Full text search using solandra

Tags: solr, cassandra, full-text-search, solandra

I already have a cassandra database which has a column with text and other column with a document ID. I want to search the text column with a few phrases for some analytical purpose. I've decided to go with Solandra. Can anyone please suggest as to how do I integrate solandra with an existing cassandra database? Any pointers to a reliable documentation will also help me.

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions of how to do it in its [github repository readme](https://github.com/tjake/Solandra/blob/solandra/README.md#embedding-in-an-existing-cassandra-distribution)

There are other solutions, [cassandra-lucene index](https://github.com/stratio/cassandra-lucene-index) that fits to your use case.